# Displaying user inputs with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

say I have an array

```
$something = @(
"first",
"second"
)
```

how can I display this to the user as

```
1. first
2. second
Selection :
```

I am able to do this by hash table and manually mapping

```
@{
1="first"
2="second"
};
```

and doing the following

```
$something.Keys | sort |% { Write-Host $_ ")" $something.Item($_) }
[int32]$constuctPayload.Action = Read-Host
```

but if need to perform this using an array how can I do this. I.e looping over the item and displaying with index for user selection. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `IndexOf()` method, to find the index in the array.

```
$something | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "$([Array]::IndexOf($something, $_)). $_ "}
```

Standard warning about being careful with `Write-Host`. Also you might want to look into `Out-GridView`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to iterate over the elements of the array and prepend each value with the index + 1.

```
$something = 'first', 'second'

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $something.Count; $i++) {
    Write-Host ('{0}. {1}' -f ($i+1), $something[$i])
}
[int32]$constuctPayload.Action = Read-Host -Prompt 'Selection'
```

I would recommend using the `PromptForChoice()` method over `Read-Host`, though:

```
$something = '&first', '&second'

$title   = 'The title.'
$msg     = 'Selection?'
$choices = $something | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription $_
}
$options = [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]] $choices
$default = 0

$constuctPayload.Action = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $msg, $options, $default)
```